# What is a "reactor"?

Tags: components

Watching some of the restoration videos of old tube/valve devices by [Mr. Carlson's Lab](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCU9SoQxJewrWb_3GxeteQPA), I've heard him describe a circuit element called a "reactor" on several occasions - for instance [here](https://youtu.be/BvbNBZX6kNE?t=1158), where the circuit includes a "saturable reactor". So far, I have not come across a component of that name. What is a reactor, how does it work and what is it used for?

Comment: First thing I did was to copy/paste "saturable reactor" into Google. First result has more than enough to answer this question.

Comment: That was the only video a _saturable_ reactor was mentioned explicitly. Trying to search just for "reactor" got me next to nowhere.

Comment: AFAIK, "reactor" is an antiquated name for an inductor. Like condenser/capacitor.

Comment: It's just an inductor with core. The core material comes to saturation, so that's why is saturable reactor - reactance.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič that's an answer, should be in the answer box below :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A saturable reactor refers to a transformer in which the saturation of an AC waveform on one side is controlled by a DC current on the other. Inductance is often referred to as reactance, because it 'reacts' with the current. Before the transistor a saturable reactor was one of the best ways to amplify signals and was used to [control V2 rockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_amplifier).

Comment: How much noise did those saturable reactors add to the signal?

Comment: @analogsystemsrf the ones I've worked with add very little noise to the signal, I can't give details but very very little noise. The main source is magnetic noise from the outside, there are ways to overcome that however.